# Extract substring from index 0 up to searched character

Tags: ruby, string, substring

I have an object called `user`. I can get its name by `user.name`, and its value has both the first name and last name such as `Jon Doe`. What is the most efficient and elegant way of grabbing the first character up until the space character so that I get `Jon`?

Comment: For a hack this will work (btw it belongs in the `User` class so that you say `user.first_name`, `not user.name.split.first`), but I think you should consider building the `first_name` and `last_name` functionality into the `User` class rather than relying on an unspecified format, which will likely lead to errors. ie (you should keep them as separate attributes, then consolidating them for the name: `class User; def name; "#{first_name} #{last_name}" end end`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will split the string on spaces, and will output the first element (in your case, this would be the first name).

```
user.name.split[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

I would say:

```
s.split[0] # s = user.name
```

or

```
s.split.first
```

These both split the string on whitespace into an array of strings and return the first element. It will still work even if only a single name is given instead of both first and last.

Answer (score 3):

```
$`
```

is precisely what you're looking for.

```
"John Doe" =~ / /
$` # => "John"
```

It's also faster than the alternatives listed in Knut's answer:

```
require 'benchmark'

TEST_LOOPS = 10_000_000
NAME = 'Jon Doe the third'

#~ p NAME.split[0]
#~ p NAME.split.first
#~ p NAME[/^\S*/]
#~ p NAME.split(/\s/, 2).first
#~ p NAME.split(/\s/, 2)[0]
#~ p NAME.split(' ', 2)[0]
#~ exit

Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('[0]') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split[0]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('[0]2regex') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split(/\s/, 2)[0]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
  b.report('[0]2string') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split(' ', 2)[0]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

b.report('first') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split.first
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
  b.report('first2regex') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split(/\s/, 2).first
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
  b.report('first2string') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split(' ', 2).first
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
  b.report('regex') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME[/^\S*/]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('dollar backtick') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME =~ / /
      $`
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

} #Benchmark
```

Gives

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
[0]              30.453000   0.797000  31.250000 ( 31.311608)
[0]2regex        21.094000   0.000000  21.094000 ( 23.651419)
[0]2string       19.188000   0.000000  19.188000 ( 20.999215)
first            34.187000   0.782000  34.969000 ( 39.935742)
first2regex      24.078000   0.000000  24.078000 ( 26.813530)
first2string     19.125000   0.000000  19.125000 ( 19.411310)
regex            13.094000   0.000000  13.094000 ( 13.242792)
dollar backtick  12.219000   0.000000  12.219000 ( 12.227719)
---------------------------------------- total: 175.017000sec

                      user     system      total        real
[0]              30.859000   0.734000  31.593000 ( 33.809723)
[0]2regex        20.891000   0.000000  20.891000 ( 21.156553)
[0]2string       18.890000   0.000000  18.890000 ( 19.997051)
first            32.516000   0.812000  33.328000 ( 36.216360)
first2regex      22.000000   0.000000  22.000000 ( 22.853772)
first2string     19.781000   0.000000  19.781000 ( 22.010805)
regex            13.359000   0.000000  13.359000 ( 14.892417)
dollar backtick  12.328000   0.000000  12.328000 ( 13.253315)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was curious, what's the fastest solution. My result was [the regex of Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565616/extract-substring-from-index-0-up-to-searched-character/6565635#6565635).

One word about split: If your name has more parts, you may stop after the first split. You may do this with

```
String#split(/\s/, 2)
```

My Benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

TEST_LOOPS = 10_000_000
NAME = 'Jon Doe the third'

#~ p NAME.split[0]
#~ p NAME.split.first
#~ p NAME[/^\S*/]
#~ p NAME.split(/\s/, 2).first
#~ p NAME.split(/\s/, 2)[0]
#~ p NAME.split(' ', 2)[0]
#~ exit

Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('[0]') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split[0]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('[0]2regex') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split(/\s/, 2)[0]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
  b.report('[0]2string') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split(' ', 2)[0]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

b.report('first') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split.first
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
  b.report('first2regex') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split(/\s/, 2).first
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
  b.report('first2string') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME.split(' ', 2).first
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report
  b.report('regex') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME[/^\S*/]
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('dollar backtick') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      NAME =~ / /
      $`
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

} #Benchmark
```

The Result:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
[0]              30.453000   0.797000  31.250000 ( 31.311608)
[0]2regex        21.094000   0.000000  21.094000 ( 23.651419)
[0]2string       19.188000   0.000000  19.188000 ( 20.999215)
first            34.187000   0.782000  34.969000 ( 39.935742)
first2regex      24.078000   0.000000  24.078000 ( 26.813530)
first2string     19.125000   0.000000  19.125000 ( 19.411310)
regex            13.094000   0.000000  13.094000 ( 13.242792)
dollar backtick  12.219000   0.000000  12.219000 ( 12.227719)
---------------------------------------- total: 175.017000sec

                      user     system      total        real
[0]              30.859000   0.734000  31.593000 ( 33.809723)
[0]2regex        20.891000   0.000000  20.891000 ( 21.156553)
[0]2string       18.890000   0.000000  18.890000 ( 19.997051)
first            32.516000   0.812000  33.328000 ( 36.216360)
first2regex      22.000000   0.000000  22.000000 ( 22.853772)
first2string     19.781000   0.000000  19.781000 ( 22.010805)
regex            13.359000   0.000000  13.359000 ( 14.892417)
dollar backtick  12.328000   0.000000  12.328000 ( 13.253315)
```

Comment: Is it ok if I incorporate my results into your answer?